# Custom Form Wizard bootstrap 5

Tags: html, jquery, django, forms, web

I currently develop custom form wizard using bootstrap 5 and jquery. Not using any plugin.

Here my html code :

```
<div class="card-inner">
  <form action="{% url 'toTANewPrj' %}" method="post" id="frmNewPrj" class="form-validate is-alter"> {% csrf_token %} <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="custom-stepper">
          <li class="custom-step active" data-step-number="1">
            <div>
              <div class="lead-text">Intro</div>
              <div class="sub-text">Define your project type and audit year.</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="custom-step" data-step-number="2">
            <div>
              <div class="lead-text">Profiles</div>
              <div class="sub-text">Define your project type and audit year.</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="custom-step" data-step-number="3">
            <div>
              <div class="lead-text">Intro</div>
              <div class="sub-text">Define your project type and audit year.</div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="custom-step-content active"> page 1 </div>
        <div class="custom-step-content">
          <h5>Project Details</h5>
          <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="PrjName">Project Name</label>
                <div class="form-control-wrap">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PrjName" name="PrjName" placeholder="Name your project here" required>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <span class="btn btn-success btn-dim" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Get from Teammate" onclick="showModalPrjTM()">
                        <em class="icon ni ni-download"></em>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-step-content"> page 3 </div>
        <div class="navigation-buttons">
          <button class="btn btn-dim btn-success" id="prevBtn" onclick="prevStep()">Previous</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextStep()">Next</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here my css :

```
.custom-stepper {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.custom-stepper > *.custom-step {
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.custom-stepper > *.custom-step::before {
    display:grid;
    content: attr(data-step-number);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #007bff;
    place-items:center;
    margin-right:1.1rem;
}

.custom-stepper > *.custom-step.active::before {
    background-color: #20c997;
    color: #fff;
}

.custom-stepper > *.custom-step.done::before {
    font-family: "Nioicon";
    content: "\e9bd";
}

.custom-step-content {
    display: none;
}

.custom-step-content.active {
    display: block;
}
.navigation-buttons
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2.5rem;
    right:2.5rem;
}
```

Also my jquery :

```
const steps = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-step");
  const stepContents = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-step-content");
  const prevBtn = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
  const nextBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
  let currentStep = 0;
  const stepCount = steps.length;
    

  function showStep(stepIndex) {
    stepContents.forEach((content, index) => {
      content.classList.remove("active");
      steps[index].classList.remove("active", "done");

      if (index === stepIndex) {
        content.classList.add("active");
        steps[index].classList.add("active");
      } else if (index < stepIndex) {
        steps[index].classList.add("done");
      }
    });

    if (stepIndex === 0) {
      prevBtn.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      prevBtn.style.display = "inline";
    }

    if (stepIndex === stepCount - 1) {
      nextBtn.style.display = "none";
      submitBtn.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
      nextBtn.style.display = "inline";
      submitBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function prevStep() {
    if (currentStep > 0) {
      currentStep--;
      showStep(currentStep);
    }
  }

  function nextStep() {
    if (currentStep < stepCount - 1) {
      currentStep++;
      showStep(currentStep);
    }
  }
showStep(currentStep);
```

My problem is :

1. Validation not working. I use dashlite template (https://dashlite.net) that use jquery-validation in their bundle.js.
2. When i go to page 2 and back again to page 1, the form automatically submitted.

Is there any mistake from this script?

Thanks for your help.